# convert php sql Result from Vertical to Horizontal

Tags: php, html, css, sql

The following code generate the result(one record) in a vertical table is there any way to convert to horizontal like with a nice styling..  in addition if possible to get certain column in a popup window using the parameter in the query, using jquery or CSS

```
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>

<?

$table = $_GET["table"];
$lon = $_GET["lon"];
$lat = $_GET["lat"];

$sql = "select
          st_geometrytype(geom) as geometrytype,
          st_area(geom) as area, *
        from $table
        where
          st_contains(
            geom,
            st_transform(
              st_setsrid(
                st_makepoint($lon, $lat),
                4326),
              2276))";

$db = pg_connect("dbname=db user=user password=pass");
$result = pg_query($db, $sql);
while( $row = pg_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
  print "<table>";
  foreach ( array_keys($row) as $column_name )
  {
    if ( $column_name <> "geom" )
    {
      print "<tr>";
      print "<th>" . $column_name . "</th>";
      print "<td>" . $row[$column_name] . "</td>";
      print "</tr>";
    }
  }
  print "</table>";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

so far I am using this CSS to style my table.

```
th
{
  text-align:right;
  padding-right:0.5em;
}

td
{
  text-align:center;
}
```

many thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are printing the `tr` at the same time the loop runs, so it will make `tr`s and obviously it will be vertical, to make it horizontal , your loop will be like this;

```
while( $row = pg_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
  print "<table>";
  print "<tr>";
  foreach ( array_keys($row) as $column )
  {
    if ( $column_name <> "geom" )
    {


      print "<th>" . $column . "</th>";

    }
  }

  print "</tr>";
  print "<tr>";  <-- this one here opening tag
  foreach ( array_keys($row) as $column_name )
  {
    if ( $column_name <> "geom" )
    {


      print "<td>" . $row[$column_name] . "</td>";

    }
  }
  print "</tr>"; <-- this one here closing tag
  print "</table>";
}
```

Comment: hi thank you for your help,  now I am getting all the result in one row ( heading)  I need the column header and row for the data.

Comment: under `print "<table>";` add `print <tr><th>Column Name 1</th><th>Column Name 2</th></tr>` Then your loop will follow under this. If you want the row names on the left just swap the tr's, td's and th's around.

Comment: is there another way I have many columns 52,  also  what about the second part of my Question I do appreciate your help. many thanks

Comment: I would ask another question for the popup. That's a radically other question. But before you open another question: try to figure it out yourself as the question stated above is way too broad and doesn't state a specific problem.

Comment: Yes, it worked perfect, thank you,   the second question is how to show specific columns eg. owner, noBeds,  in a popup window. using the same table.  Regards

Answer (score 0):

code for display 8 elements horizontally.

```
   <table>
   <?if($c==8){echo "<tr >";$c=0;  }<td> ?>
   // your elements 
   <? echo "</td>";
   $c++;?>
   </tr>
  </table>
```